# Java, setting borders to a button after clicked messes up another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

As mentioned in the title I have a JButton, which when clicked, I want to add a border to it.The probelm is that when I am trying to add that border it completely messes up another JPanel I have, and repositions everything on it.
Here is the code for my mouseClicked:

```
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
                    if (ev.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        Object source = ev.getSource();
                        Border border;
                        if (source instanceof JButton) {
                            border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
                            ((JButton)source).setBorder(border);
                            System.out.println("Double clicked");
                        }
                    } else if (ev.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        Object source = ev.getSource();
                        Border border;
                        if(source instanceof JButton){
                            border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
                            ((JButton)source).setBorder(border);
                            System.out.println("Clicked");
                        }
                    }
                }
        });
```

Also, as you can tell, I remove that borded when the button is Double-Clicked.

*Extra info: I tried removing the `((JButton)source).setBorder(border);` command, and it seems to not have any problems without it.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What is the point of  `JButton neo;   neo = ((JButton)source);` ?

Comment: I am sorry for including that to my code, it was just for some testing porpuses. I'll remove it now.

Comment: What do you mean by "messes up another JPanel"? Could you please add a screenshot?

Comment: 1) For a `JButton`, use an `ActionListener`. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) A `JRadioButton` seems better suited to this task.

Answer (score 2):

> The probelm is that when I am trying to add that border it completely messes up another JPanel

```
border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
```

That creates a Border with the line thickness of 1 I would guess.

```
border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
```

That creates a Border with the line thickness of 0.

So changing the Border causes the size of the button to change which can affect the layout.

Instead you should be using:

```
border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

This will keep the size of the button from changing so it should not cause a layout issue. However, this Border should also be the default Border for the button.

Comment: @Μιχάλης, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.